# How can I resolve this pip issue?

Tags: software-installation, python3, pip

I am trying to use `pip` to install *Flask* on Ubuntu.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
user_1@dell-vostro:~$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
[sudo] password for user_1: 
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/bd/2410905c76ee14c62baf69e3f4aa780226c1bbfc9485731ad018e35b0cb5/pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.1MB 631kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-22.3.1

user_1@dell-vostro:~$ pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_1/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/user_1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

user_1@dell-vostro:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_1/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/user_1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


user_1@dell-vostro:~$
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Why are you using `pip3` for the first command but `pip` for the second? My first guess is that this results in python2 running python3 code. Does using `pip3` for all commands work as expected?

Comment: @terdon, *Does using pip3 for all commands work as expected?* --- No.

Comment: Ah well. Worth a try. Please [edit] your question and show the output of using `pip3` instead of `pip` to keep things consistent and avoid others going down the same wrong route I did.

Comment: @terdon, I just removed Python 2.7. Now, neither pip3 not pip works.

Comment: You what? You actually uninstalled python2!?

Comment: @terdon, yes...

Comment: Oh wow. OK, that is a whole new issue and far more serious. I suggest opening a new question, but it might be better to ask on our sister site, [ubuntu.se] since that's where the Ubuntu folks hang out. There will still be various system scripts and tools that rely on python2 so I fear that uninstalling it will have broken all sorts of things.

Comment: Since the system version of `python3` is 3.5, I'm betting that https://askubuntu.com will close the question for being off-topic.